# Delete the row in 2d vector

Tags: c++

I have a 2D vector, and i want to delete some rows of it. 
The original vector look like:

Tick    On/Off  Note    Von Voff    Duration

245 144 64  62  64  1132
261 144 41  73  64  1197
272 144 69  116 64  1108
293 144 72  102 64  1060
1353    128 72  64
1377    128 64  64
1380    128 69  64
1458    128 41  64
1519    144 40  83  64  1321
1519    144 62  83  64  1176
1547    144 68  93  64  1167
1564    144 72  116 64  1135
2695    128 62  64
2699    128 72  64
2714    128 68  64
2819    144 60  79  64  1294
2840    128 40  64
2857    144 45  89  64  1322
2874    144 67  97  64  1204
2905    144 71  112 64  1173
4078    128 67  64
4078    128 71  64
4113    128 60  64
4179    128 45  64

I have some problems to do that.

I tried to used the code:

```
void DeleteNoteOff(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &eventStore){
  for(int i = 0; i<eventStore.size(); i++){
    if(eventStore[i][1] == 128){
      eventStore.erase(eventStore.begin()+i);
    }
  }
}
```

The result is not deleting completely.

Tick    On/Off  Note    Von Voff    Duration

245 144 64  62  64  1132
261 144 41  73  64  1197
272 144 69  116 64  1108
293 144 72  102 64  1060
1377    128 64  64
1458    128 41  64
1519    144 40  83  64  1321
1519    144 62  83  64  1176
1547    144 68  93  64  1167
1564    144 72  116 64  1135
2699    128 72  64
2819    144 60  79  64  1294
2857    144 45  89  64  1322
2874    144 67  97  64  1204
2905    144 71  112 64  1173
4078    128 71  64
4179    128 45  64

Need help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with input and desired output.

Comment: I wanna delete all the rows with "128" as the second element.

Comment: And you posted a small code snippet that doesn't show your whole code. Your question probably will be closed if you don't post a [mcve] that can be compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanna delete all the rows with "128" as the second element.

There is no need to write a loop to do this.

Erasing all items from a vector that satisfy a certain criteria can be done by using the [std::remove_if / std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm along with `vector::erase`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void DeleteNoteOff(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &eventStore)
{
   eventStore.erase(std::remove_if(eventStore.begin(), eventStore.end(), 
                    [](const std::vector<int>& v) {return v.size() > 1 && v[1] == 128;}), 
                    eventStore.end());
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> test = {{245,144,64,62,64,1132},
                                        {261,144,41,73,64,1197},
                                        {272,144,69,116,64,1108},
                                        {293,144,72,102,64,1060},
                                        {1353,128,72,64},
                                        {1377,128,64,64},
                                        {1380,128,69,64},
                                        {1458,128,41,64},
                                        {1519,144,40,83,64,1321},
                                        {1519,144,62,83,64,1176},
                                        {1547,144,68,93,64,1167},
                                        {1564,144,72,116,64,1135},
                                        {2695,128,62,64},
                                        {2699,128,72,64},
                                        {2714,128,68,64},
                                        {2819,144,60,79,64,1294},
                                        {2840,128,40,64},
                                        {2857,144,45,89,64,1322},
                                        {2874,144,67,97,64,1204},
                                        {2905,144,71,112,64,1173},
                                        {4078,128,67,64},
                                        {4078,128,71,64},
                                        {4113,128,60,64},
                                        {4179,128,45,64}};
    DeleteNoteOff(test);
    for (auto& v : test)
    {
       std::cout << "{";
       for (auto& v2 : v)
          std::cout << v2 << " ";
       std::cout << "}\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{245 144 64 62 64 1132 }
{261 144 41 73 64 1197 }
{272 144 69 116 64 1108 }
{293 144 72 102 64 1060 }
{1519 144 40 83 64 1321 }
{1519 144 62 83 64 1176 }
{1547 144 68 93 64 1167 }
{1564 144 72 116 64 1135 }
{2819 144 60 79 64 1294 }
{2857 144 45 89 64 1322 }
{2874 144 67 97 64 1204 }
{2905 144 71 112 64 1173 }
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/042729deeb5e270e)

Quick explanation:

`std::remove_if` moves all of the items that need to be removed to the end of the `eventStore` vector.  The return value of `std::remove_if` is an iterator to the start of the removed items.

The `remove_if` criteria is specified by a lambda function that takes the individual inner vector and checks if the second value in the vector is 128 (note the check to make sure the vector has at least 2 items).  If the return value from the lambda function is `true` then that vector will be "removed" (i.e. moved to the end of `eventStore`).

Then last, the `eventStore.erase` takes this return value from `remove_if` and erases all the items starting at where the moved (removed) items start until the end of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You are also increasing `i` in each iteration when deleting an element, which should not be happening (since this ends up in skipping some vectors containing 128. More specifically it would skip the 2nd, 4th, 6th consecutive appearance - as it does). Use this instead:

```
void DeleteNoteOff(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &eventStore) {
  for(int i = 0; i<eventStore.size(); ) {
    if(eventStore[i][1] == 128) {
      eventStore.erase(eventStore.begin()+i);
    }
    else {
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

I removed the increment of `i++` to only be done when no element is erased.